# display FULL NEWS using ASP.NET RSS

Tags: asp.net, rss

I use the following code to display RSS news topic and summary, it works fine but I want to display the whole news in my own site, now my users can click on news link and whole news is visible in the main site, but I want it to be displayed in my site. is is possible? can I use RSS to display the whole content in my own site or I should parse the main news page and display it in my site? I think it is very difficult to parse this page.

my server code:

```
//Create a WebRequest
        WebRequest rssReq =
        WebRequest.Create("myRSSsite");
        //Create a Proxy
        WebProxy px = new WebProxy("myRSSsite", true);
        //Assign the proxy to the WebRequest
        rssReq.Proxy = px;
        //Set the timeout in Seconds for the WebRequest
        rssReq.Timeout = 5000;
        try
        {
            //Get the WebResponse
            WebResponse rep = rssReq.GetResponse();
            //Read the Response in a XMLTextReader
            XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(rep.GetResponseStream());
            //Create a new DataSet
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //Read the Response into the DataSet
            ds.ReadXml(xtr);
            //Bind the Results to the Repeater
            rssRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
            rssRepeater.DataBind();
```

also I use a repeater on my ASPX page to display RSS, but I have a list containing news title (linking to the main site) and a small summary, nothing more! is there any way I can get the whole news HTML so that I can store it in my database?

Comment: First of all, does the RSS feed include the whole news story? Some RSS feeds only contain a summary. When that's sorted out, can you post the code for your `ASPX` page, so we can see the HTML?

Comment: thanks, how can I understand if my RSS contains full story? I can see only a linked title and a brief summary, but when I click on the title link, main page is displayed which contains whole story and some images also, how can I find this?

Comment: Can you post a link to the RSS feed if it's public? Or post the XML from the feed?

Comment: unfortunately there are not English, I'm going to use several sites, and they are all Persian, an example: http://www.bartarinha.ir/fa/rss/15, how can I find XML?

Comment: An RSS feed is XML. Using Google Chrome, try this link: view-source:http://www.bartarinha.ir/fa/rss/15 Then you can see that the RSS does not include the whole story. It only has a description. So you can't get then entire news content from the RSS feed. Only way around this, is to site-scrape the content.

Comment: thanks Martin, I've saved one of the links, and I'm analyzing the HTML, I've found that it has 3 main DIVs, title, summary and body (which contains whole story), how can I have them in my database? it is what you called site-scrape? would you plz describe it a little more? any sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site scrape the news article using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
var element = doc.GetElementbyId("Id-of-the-article-body-element");
string content = element.OuterHtml;
```

If the article body element doesn't have an ID, you have to use an XPath query to find it. Take a look at this [tutorial on HTML Agility Pack](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx).

Comment: Oh yes, it's awesome. Glad you could use it.

Comment: I think it can be used for web crawling also, I'm going to work on a search engine project and this seems to be a great tool.